# Extjs Button click invokes menuitem by default

Tags: extjs4

One of the options for a menu is considered "typical". As in most people would click the first menu item. But there is a second option for those outside cases. Therefore, I would like a button menu that has a default option for those that do not want to have to click twice for the "typical" option. I was thinking that the handler for a button would:

- stop showing the menu (I tried `event.stopEvent()` without success.)
- invoke the handler for one of the menu items.

But you could still access the menu if you clicked the dropdown icon that appears next to the button.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Litote0707/kNbTE/).

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'Pick One',
    menu: {
        items: [{
            text: 'Thing 1!',
            handler: function () {
                alert('foo');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Thing 2!',
            handler: function () {
                alert('bar');
            }
        }]
    },
    handler: function (theButton, event) {
        //stop the menu from showing
        //event.stopEvent(); //try to stop showing menu, but no luck

        //invoke the handler for menu item 1
        //try to get at handler for menuitem programmatically
        //theButton.menu.items.getAt(0).??? 

        //i'd settle for hard-coding the function
        //alert('foo'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the point of having a menu if you're just going to trigger one of the items directly? Why not just have the button handler do it?

Comment: i want there to be a menu of options (which is available by clicking that dropdown icon) but there to be a default option for the lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you should use a split button:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#split-buttons

The menu will only show up when you click the arrow part. When you click the button part, it will fire the button handler and not show the menu.